# bootstrap tooltip does not work in chrome (on deployment only)?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, browser, tooltip

I'm using bootstrap's tooltip and it's working fine on different browsers (including chrome) when it runs local.

When I'm running it online it does not respond in chrome, but in safari for example it does.
This is my jquery code for initiating:

```
 $('#cdssdemo, #contactemail, #contactphone')
   .tooltip()
   .click(function(e) { 
       e.preventDefault(); 
       $(this).focus(); 
   });
```

This is an example element for tooltip:

```
<li>
    <a href="tel:0000">
        <i class="fa fa-phone" data-toggle="tooltip" title="0000" id="contactphone"></i>
    </a>
</li>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please share a demo or a jsfiddle?

Comment: tried any debugging? Get and JS errors, give us more info.

Comment: I did try debugging. Edited the question for more details

Comment: It's almost impossible to solve that problem with those limited details. Since you've mentioned that it runs well on local but not online, I would say that there's might be a conflict / cache problem, but a demo or a jsfiddle is a must in order to solve it, otherwise - we're just guessing.

Comment: This is the problematic website: http://home.pharmpool.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was chrome cached my older js files. When I try in Incognito Mode it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you could put a working example in JSFiddle, we could have more to go off of.  But, maybe you could try something like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#cdssdemo, #contactemail, #contactphone')
       .tooltip()
       .click(function(e) { 
           e.preventDefault(); 
           $(this).focus(); 
    });
});
```

Otherwise, there are a few other stackoverflow articles that suggest things that you could try.

> [Bootstrap tooltip doesn't show style of the tooltip, only data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146550/bootstrap-tooltip-doesnt-show-style-of-the-tooltip-only-data)
>
> [Bootstrap's javascript works locally but not when deployed to a
>   server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139670/bootstraps-javascript-works-locally-but-not-when-deployed-to-a-server)
>
> [Bootstrap tooltips not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9446318/bootstrap-tooltips-not-working)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it does not. This is the exact js I used for my project. Here us the problematic website: http://home.pharmpool.com/